# Signal not caught when sending SIGUSR1 or SIGINT to stopped process until you continue the process -- why?

Tags: process, signals

Why is it that when you stop a process and then try to terminate it with SIGUSR1 or SIGINT, the signal isn't caught until you send SIGCONT? But when you terminate it with SIGKILL, the signal is caught right away?

In our own shell, we followed this in gdb. The signal isn't caught at all until continuing the process. Our SIGCHLD handler for the parent process caught it after we sent a SIGCONT signal, and WIFSIGNALED(status) for the child process returned true (meaning the signal wasn't caught before, right?).

Regular Linux shell sending SIGUSR1 to a stopped process:

```
$ ./testing 30
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./testing 30
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2775 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
 4668 pts/2    00:00:00 testing
 4669 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
$ kill -SIGUSR1 4668
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2775 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
 4668 pts/2    00:00:00 testing
 4670 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
$ kill -SIGCONT 4668
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2775 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
 4671 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
[1]+  User defined signal 1   ./testing 30
$
```

Regular Linux shell sending SIGINT to a stopped process:

```
$ ./testing 30
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./testing 30
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2775 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
 4691 pts/2    00:00:00 testing
 4692 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
$ kill -SIGINT 4691
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2775 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
 4691 pts/2    00:00:00 testing
 4702 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
$ kill -SIGCONT 4691
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2775 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
 4703 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
[1]+  Interrupt               ./testing 30
$
```

Regular Linux shell sending SIGKILL to a stopped process:

```
$ ./testing 30
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./testing 30
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 5243 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
 5331 pts/2    00:00:00 testing
 5332 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
$ kill -SIGKILL 5331
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 5243 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
 5334 pts/2    00:00:00 ps
[1]+  Killed                  ./testing 30
$
```

Answer (score 1):

`SIGKILL` cannot be blocked. `SIGUSR1` and `SIGINT` can.

Comment: So does sending a SIGTSTP signal automatically block those?

Comment: It depends what the code asks for. If you use `sigaction`, for example, you can control it by setting the `sa_mask` parameter.

Comment: I'm asking in context of the default linux shell, running a simple loop program without any special handlers. (the whole my own shell thing was just to see where the signal was in gdb)

Comment: If you don't ask for anything special, you don't get anything special.

Comment: So "nothing special", the default, is that SIGTSTP automatically blocks these signals? Thanks.

Comment: You got it. If you don't ask, you get what everyone else gets.